# Codeigniter 2 Scaffolding

Tags: php, codeigniter, crud, scaffolding

What are my options when dealing with scaffolding in codeigniter - do people use scaffolding often? Or is there a better way of quickly generating code to be used in CRUD applications?

I've installed sparkplug: http://code.google.com/p/sparkplug/

And it seems pretty good - I mean it's basic but super fast to implement and the code is basic but neat and easy to understand.

However I noticed that there is not much discusson surrounding the benefits/drawbacks.

Can anyone advise a) a good library/ set of tools to use?
b) How best to proceed in this situation

Comment: Have you tried this? http://git.io/dV8HCQ

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The idea of temporary scaffolding CRUD has always seemed a bit pointless to me for a couple reasons:

- It's not an end game solution, you're going to have to eventually implement proper (secure) CRUD operations for your application that are better tailored to your specific application's needs.
- If you just need quick and dirty DB input, Why not just use your DBMS? (phpMyAdmin, etc...)

To mitigate the time spent on repetitive application operations, I actually create a basic CRUD model so that I can have a good starting point to build the basic database interaction.  That way you will actually be progressing towards your applications completion.

Comment: "If you just need quick and dirty DB input, Why not just use your DBMS? (phpMyAdmin, etc...)" scaffolding, in theory, makes it easier to enter relationship data than doing it manually (ie tracking FKs).

Answer (score 8):

Scaffolding only ever existed to save you having to crack open Navicat, phpMyAdmin, MySQL Query Builder, etc. But this day in age, if you dont know how to work a MySQL client then you probably shouldn't be be working on a bloody website so it's been removed.

Comment: I'm actually not allowed to connect to our MySQL install unless I go up to IT and use a specific computer to remote into a computer in Winnipeg.

Comment: If they are that much of a freak about security then you should be building locally and deploying code (using migrations) which has been peer reviewed and extensively tested, not using insecure unprotected PHP interface to edit data on the live server - because THAT is ridiculous.

Answer (score 2):

The reason I prefer to use a "quick and dirty" CRUD generator is often we bring in several non-technical people to do data clean-up.  If I can easily build this "throw-away" interface without having to do a lot of coding, it saves me a lot of time as well as I am not spending much time on coding "throw-away" pages.  I don't really want to give non-technical people an Admin tool just to edit data.